# variable field in an "if"

Tags: django, python-3.x

how can I force the insertion of this "fascia" variable here:

```
fascia = input("fascia [1-9]:")
    if iscritti.corso+fascia+_id==None:
    ...

contatore1= Iscrizione.objects.filter(corso+fascia+_id=corsi)
```

Comment: Don't. Use a list or a dictionary.